# Rails server getting error on the starting point

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have started a project to update, which was updated also a couple of months ago, but today it's not running on the development, I have deleted `Gemfile.lock` and reinstall the gems & update the bundler but showing still.

Here are below I have attached the full specification of this project.

```
// Environment
$ ruby -v
 - ruby 3.0.1p64 (2021-04-05 revision 0fb782ee38) [x86_64-darwin20]

$ rails -v
  - Rails 5.2.6

$ bundle -v
  - Bundler version 2.2.31

macOS v12.0.1
```

When running the `rails server` it's showing like this below

```
user@Users-MacBook-Pro max-domain % rails server            
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.6 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.6/lib/active_record/type/adapter_specific_registry.rb:9:in `add_modifier': wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2) (ArgumentError)
.........
....
```

I don't even find any clue where can I fix that!

Would you please help me out with that?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Ruby 3.0.1 you need to be on Rails 6.1 (and above). Max ruby version for Rails 5.2 is 2.7.0.

Here's a [compatibility table](https://www.fastruby.io/blog/ruby/rails/versions/compatibility-table.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the project was running nicely before today! I didn't change or update anything there.

Comment: Something must have changed right? Otherwise you wouldn't have the error. It's the ruby version for sure.